# How to use Jsdoc to describe an extended class's property that is defined in super class

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc, es6-class, javascript-intellisense

What I want to do is this:

```
class A {
  someMethod() {
    //
  }
}

class B {
  constructor (options) {
    this.dependency = options.dependency;
  }
}


class C extends B {
  test() { 
    this.dependency.a. // want a to refer to instance of A class and provide intellisense using jsdocs
  }
}
```

I have tried some stuff on normal objects and it works but I can't get it working on the class or override some property.
here is what I have tried:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} WithSomeProp
 * @property {{ a: A }} prop
 * 
 * @typedef {C & WithSomeProp} extended
 */

/**
 * @type {extended}
 */
let a = {};
a.prop.a.someMethod // works (shows suggestion)
a.test // works

/**
 * @typedef {Object} WithOtherProp
 * @property {{ a: A }} dependency
 * 
 * @typedef {C & WithOtherProp} extendedTwo
 */

/**
 * @type {extendedTwo}
 */
let b = {};
b.dependency. // doesn't work
b.test // works
```

So overall there isn't any way to override the property definition somehow later on the extended classes to get intellisense support ?

Answer (score 1):

I just realized I can do this instead (I feel dumb now)

```js
class C extends B {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    /**
     * @type {A}
     */
    this.a = options.dependency.a;
  }
  test() { 
    this.a.someMethod // works fine now
  }
}
```